# Terraform merge/combine two outputs into one

Tags: terraform

I want to merge these JSONs into one under keys in Terraform. But I have got overwritten values or many keys.

Desirable terraform output:

```json
"test_01": {
  "app-server": {
    "ansible_playbook": "playbook.yml",
    "external_ip": "app-ip"
  },
  "db-server": {
    "ansible_playbook": "playbook-02.yml",
    "external_ip": "db-ip"
  }
}
```

**One:**

```json
"test_01": {
  "app-server": {
    "ansible_playbook": "playbook.yml"
  },
  "db-server": {
    "ansible_playbook": "playbook-02.yml"
  }
}
```

**Second**

```json
"test_02": {
  "app-server": {
    "external_ip": "app-ip"
  },
  "db-server": {
    "external_ip": "db-ip"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this s static config or this is just an exmaple but your real example is more complex? this feels like it would be much easier to acheive in ansible its self.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle 
, thank you. Yes, it is more complicated. 
The main idea is to have separate Ansible playbooks for each server. 
It looks like I need to look for another semiautomated solution.

Vultr module. https://github.com/rmalenko/terraform-vultr-stacks/tree/dev

Comment: if you are using some pipeline for your deployments, you could build up these jsons by initiating the merge before passing it into terraform , and then pass the outputted json into the terraform plan via ' -var '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of this answer I'm going to assume that you have child modules `module.a` and `module.b`.

`module.a` has an output value `playbooks`:

```
tomap({
  "app-server" = {
    ansible_playbook = "playbook.yml"
  }
  "db-server" = {
    ansible_playbook = "playbook-02.yml"
  }
})
```

`module.b` has an output value `ip_addresses`:

```
tomap({
  "app-server" = {
    external_ip = "app-ip"
  },
  "db-server": {
    external_ip = "db-ip"
  }
})
```

In the module that calls both `module.a` and `module.b` you want to return a merged output value `ansible` with the following content:

```
tomap({
  "app-server" = {
    ansible_playbook = "playbook.yml",
    external_ip      = "app-ip"
  }
  "db-server" = {
    ansible_playbook = "playbook-02.yml",
    external_ip      = "db-ip"
  }
})
```

One way to achieve that would be as follows:

```
output "ansible" {
  value = tomap({
    for k in keys(module.b.ip_addresses) : k => {
      ansible_playbook = module.a.playbooks[k].ansible_playbook
      external_ip      = module.b.ip_addresses[k].ansible_playbook
    }
  })
}
```

This is a [`for` expression](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for), which is the general solution for deriving one collection from another. In this case, the input collection is the set of keys from `module.b.ip_addresses`, and the result is a mapping from `k` to an object type including both `ansible_playbook` and `external_ip` derived from the corresponding elements of the other maps.

The above assumes that the set of keys in `module.a.playbooks` and `module.b.ip_addresses` will always exactly match. If not, you will either have missing entries in the derived output value or Terraform will return an error saying that `k` is not present in `module.a.playbooks`.